# How to check for screen activation in system logs

Tags: linux, debian, logging, systemd, event-log

I have a Debian 10 (Buster) installed, and I was wondering how to check in the system logs when the screen was activated.

The way I configured the OS is that I have turned off in the power manager the hibernation/suspend/screensaver, and have only set the display power management, to turn off the display after 30 minutes, so that after 30 minutes the screen turns off but everything else is running and if I press any key on the keyboard it turns back on.

Where can I check in the system logs when the screen was turned back on either by key presses or otherwise. Is there a log of when the screen is switched on or off? And where?